# GCP taggable asset types

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How to get types of all taggable GCP assets? (Assets that can have tags).

All I found was this table in documentation https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/tags/tags-supported-services#supported_service_resources
But it doesn't contain full asset type name, like, for example, VM has this asset type `compute.googleapis.com/Instance`, instead in documentation is says "Compute Engine" - "Instances".